# Why signalR can't send message to the client when it run on the docker with nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: docker, nginx, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi, nginx-location

I can receive the message sent by the signalR hub when it run on the localhost, but when I put my program on the server which is using nginx reverse proxy, I can connect to the signalR hub but can't receive message from it. I don't know why? Is it the proplem of nginx.conf configuration file? Besides, I can see the website icon when I run it on localhost, but can't when it run on the linux server no matter whether using nginx reverse proxy.

I try to modify the nginx.conf file,I tried all of these command:
proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;or:
proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";or:
proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
I don't know what the problem is.

```
server {
server_name www.website.com;
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate 1_www.website.com_bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key 2_www.website.com.key;
ssl_session_timeout 5m;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!RC4:!DHE;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

location / {
proxy_pass http://www.website.com:5050;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;


}
}
```

I expect the signalR hub run on the server can send message to client, but now I can only make it when the program run on my localhost.
Thanks for help.
Frank

Comment: Have you tried to bypass nginx for testing? This way you could figure out if nginx is the problem or your service.

Comment: I just tried. I can receive message from signalR without using nginx and the website icon also showed , but when using nginx , I can't receive message and there is no website icon. It seems the problem is from nignx.